# Get function parameter names and types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I've played around with the `Parameters<T>` type in TypeScript, which returns a tuple with the parameter types. Now I wonder if there's a way to not just return the types of the paramters but also the names?

Something like:

```
function MyFunc(a: string, b: boolean, ...args: string[]) {}

type extractedType = ParametersWithName<typeof MyFunc>
```

Where `extractedType` results ends up as:

```
{
    a: string, 
    b: string
}
```

I would use that to convert from regular function parameters to functions that receive a parameter object (like React props).

Comment: in typescript 4 `Parameters` also returns names as [`Labeled Tuple Elements
`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#labeled-tuple-elements). But still I don't know a way to convert it to object. `keyof extractedType` still doesn't return the names (but do return array props which are irrelevant in this case)

Comment: Yeah, as of yet parameter names are not observable in the type system except as documentation for IntelliSense :/

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Currently it is impossible to convert between function parameter names or [tuple element labels](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#labeled-tuple-elements) and string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types).  There is a feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#44939](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44939) asking to support type-level manipulations of function parameter names and tuple labels.  It's currently marked as "Awaiting More Feedback", so if you need this functionality you might want to go there, give it a , and explain why your use case is compelling and why alternatives aren't sufficient.

Until and unless that gets implemented, though, parameter names are not part of a function's type.  For example, the type signatures `(foo: string) => void` and `(bar: string) => void` are completely identical as far as type compatibility is concerned.  The names `foo` and `bar` are (usually) preserved by IntelliSense as a form of documentation to help developers, but they are essentially implementation details.

And since there isn't supposed to be a way to distinguish two function types that differ only by parameter names, there's no mechanism provided to convert these names into string literal types for use as object keys.   If there *were* to be a way to do this, it would need to be subtle enough not to break function type compatibility, possibly via some sort of special magic/intrinsic type function.

---

The ability to convert between function parameter lists and tuple types was [introduced in TypeScript 3.0](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions) via [microsoft/TypeScript#24897](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897).  This is what makes `Parameters<>` possible.  That pull request has the following remark about parameter names:

> Note that when a tuple type is inferred from a sequence of parameters and later expanded into a parameter list, ... the original parameter names are used in the expansion (however, the names have no semantic meaning and are not otherwise observable).

[Labeled tuple elements](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#labeled-tuple-elements) introduced in TypeScript 4.0 allow you to convert between parameter names and tuple labels, but neither of these are observable to the type system as string literal types.

So there's definitely no way to use `Parameters<>` or something like it to pull parameter names out of a function and use them.