# Typescript Interface Type from Parameters<>

Tags: typescript

While adding an abstraction layer to a third-party library, I want to pass an object that contains some information + the library's function parameters along but cannot get the right conversion.

```
// Types from Lib
type LibData = any | any[]
type LibOpts = { [key: string]: any }
type ExternalLibFunction = (data: LibData, opts?: LibOpts) => any

// Parameters<ExternalLibraryFunction> = [data: LibData, opts?: LibOpts]
type LibFunctionParameters = Parameters<ExternalLibFunction>

// How to convert LibFunctionParameters to...?
type LibParametersKeyed = {
  data: LibData
  opts?: LibOpts
}

// Use Example
type RunSet = { foo: any } & LibParametersKeyed
```

The library is [`xlsx` on `npm`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx) if that helps

Comment: Whare are `LibData` and `LibOptions`?

Comment: Then what do they have to do with your `LibParameters`?  `LibParameters` is not used anywhere in your current codeblock

Comment: It appears that this may not be possible, at least as of 2019.  Check out [Get function parameter names and types in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57995936/12010984) for a good explanation of why

Comment: Generally it's best for example code not to have undeclared types in them; could you fix that so that it's a [mre]?  You can't convert between tuple element labels and string literal types, so there's no way to do it automatically.  You can manually write out the mapping from tuple position to key name.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55522477/typescript-create-tuple-from-interface) is the reverse question.  If you produce a [mre] there is a way to do it with something like `Convert<LibParameters, ["data", "opts"]>`; would that be acceptable to you?

Comment: When you link an answer from @jcalz at the same time that he shows up and posts a comment of his own (⁎⁀⎵⁀⁎)

Comment: @jcalz - I edited the question to expand the example definitions. Yes, a `Convert<LibParameters, ["data", "opts"]>` is still much more useful than trying to dive into the library and isn't much more work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Tuple element labels](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#labeled-tuple-elements) are purely for documentation purposes.  Like function parameter names, they have no effect on type compatibility and are completely unobservable in the type system. They cannot be extracted to string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types).  See [microsoft/TypeScript#31627](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31627) for a declined request to extract function parameter names to string literals.

For example, the following types are completely equivalent:

```
// tuple labels are unobservable in the type system
declare var x: [data: LibData, opts?: LibOpts];
declare var x: [foo: LibData, bar?: LibOpts];
declare var x: [LibData, LibOpts?];
```

So there's no way to get `"data"` and `"opts"` out of the `ExternalLibFunction` or `LibFunctionParameters` types.

If you want to be able to turn `LibFunctionParameters` into `{data: LibData, opts?: LibObpts}`, you'll need to supply the ordered list of key names yourself. Meaning the transformation would look like `TupleToObject<LibFunctionParameters, ["data", "opts"]>` for some suitably-defined `TupleToObject` type function.

Let's define it.

---

Given a general tuple type `T` and another tuple `K` of the same length whose elements are key names, you can convert the tuple `T` to an object with keys in `K` and whose values are the corresponding value from `T` like this:

```
type TupleToObject<T extends any[], K extends { [I in keyof T]: PropertyKey }> = {
    [I in keyof T as I extends keyof any[] ? never : K[I]]: T[I]
}
```

`TupleToObject<T>` uses [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) to turn each index `I` of the `T` tuple into a key from `K` (`K[I]` is the `I`<sup>th</sup> element of the `K` tuple).  Note that `I in keyof T as` iterates over all the keys in `T`, including array properties and method keys like `"push"` or `"length"` or `number` (see [microsoft/TypeScript#40586](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40586) for a request to change this); we don't want to deal with those, so we filter them out by writing `I extends keyof any[] ? never :` to suppress them.

Let's verify that it works for your example:

```
type LibParametersKeyed = TupleToObject<LibFunctionParameters, ["data", "opts"]>

/* type LibParametersKeyed = {
    data: LibData;
    opts?: LibOpts | undefined;
} */
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgDLAEYBE5jsgbwChlTkMIxIoAVAeyzpoAtgBnALmThAE9kAPtz4BtALpEAvkVDV4SNJgDyABzBtCyEQGsIvLmzBRQAczFce-aWF4qUAUQAe1EHAA26DADEAriARgwHQgyAC8yAAUACa4cFyeOHgANMh0amwA-PHK6QCUYQB8wrxEpUQA9OXIAApwUHAAtpTQbAA8Ti7unvVQvL7+gcFF4SIxeNnYsSlp6lmKGKrqEjZ28-0BQSC19U3UGuHbjc1QbR3Qrh6Y64MgBaWVyGA+Km4obnAUbhp1KH50GGxoAA3D6vZCgR7MFArFBsXiGCANIhRCAId5QFAgqDIRxcUaxCaJODTdJzTyLNhiADcyNR6MxdRxeJgdDohKm5DqZJySxpKLRP2QWKZWgSHPJpOppRhyBoz1e9CUGAAVqiwK0aMgIM4ICAot9RGIUgBpLU6vUaAhaACS4JCul4dBgsvMNSgaWgNmNemQkmGhBIZBEtohDqdsu4Glt2sgFuQYedlnEyAyyBAECB0GQXGNwbErpoeak0tsKE8h12LW9vAgUTCsvlEEVKrVrU8102FeObBSIgARGM4H2Un2Zmw+2I7uUAFSPUvzLt7au1+vEMjIQfsvA09dj7kLdKCZB+FEwUC1mmSZDT8plB4AVUByCcjReECIMoASn4AMqUVfICybLFL6yAAGQLnURxLnotZAA)

Comment: This is wonderful, thank you! Didn't get a chance to properly write a note yesterday but wanted to let you know the effort and time to answer is very altruistic and appreciated. Many thanks :) - @jcalz