# TypeScript object type who's properties are required arguments of a class constructor

Tags: typescript, generics

I want to create a generic TypeScript object type who's properties are composed of required arguments of a class constructor. For example, if I had this class:

```
class Example {
  constructor(
    public readonly foo: string,
    public readonly bar: number,
    public readonly option?: number,
  ) {}
}
```

I'd like a type (or interface) like this:

```
type ExampleArgs = {
  foo: string,
  bar: number
}
```

I'd like it to be generic so the type will be inferred from any class.

I got close with this:

```
type ConstructorArgs<T> = T extends new (...args: infer Args) => any
  ? Required<{ [K in keyof Args]: Args[K] }>
  : never;
```

But that creates an array type. Using it like this:

```
type ExampleArgs = ConstructorArgs<typeof Example>; // [foo: string, bar: number, option: number]
```

Will result in: `[foo: string, bar: number, option: number]`

What I'd like to do is drop the optional `option` argument and transform the type into an object. Is that possible?

Comment: What are you gonna use the resulting type for?

Comment: Will the class have any other properties defined outside of the constructor?

Comment: To my eyes this is constructor version of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57993250/get-function-parameter-names-and-types-in-typescript - hence the answer is that it is impossible. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69687087/transform-named-tuple-to-object

Comment: Yeah this is impossible unless you're willing to supply a helper type like `["foo", "bar", "option"]`.  You *can* detect and remove the optional properties, but if one piece of your task is impossible then the whole thing is.

Comment: @vr it's to help with type safety in dependencies between different parts of the application. For example, one part of the application needs to save a payload into a document database. Getting type safety like this would ensure that the Class Factory used  in another part of the application has all the constructor parameters it needs.

Comment: It looks like what I asked for is not possible by reading the duplicate posts. Thanks all!